# Regular Expression to Match Entire Java Exception Stacktrace

Tags: java, regex, logging, grep

Given a standard log file for a java application:

```
 INFO [main] (AutoMain.java:133) - querying data 1
DEBUG [main] (AutoMain.java:142) - data 1 count: 23180
 INFO [main] (AutoMain.java:151) - querying data 2
ERROR [main] (AutoMain.java:607) - Failure in auto
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory$1.<init>(ClientIOFactory.java:17)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory.lambda$clientIOFactoryFromSocket$0(ClientIOFactory.java:15)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:83)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:91)
    at com.myCompany.queryOptData(InstantAutomaton.java:153)
    at com.myCompany.AutoMain.main(InstantAutomaton.java:426)
```

**What is a regular expression to match the entire stack trace for any java `Exception`?**

It's easy enough to match any single line that contains "Exception":

```
grep "Exception" log.txt
```

But I want all of the subsequent "at" statements as well.  So the result matched string should be:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory$1.<init>(ClientIOFactory.java:17)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory.lambda$clientIOFactoryFromSocket$0(ClientIOFactory.java:15)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:83)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:91)
    at com.myCompany.queryOptData(InstantAutomaton.java:153)
    at com.myCompany.AutoMain.main(InstantAutomaton.java:426)
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Try `(?m)^.*?Exception.*(?:[\r\n]+^\s*at .*)+`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/0snwpw/1

Comment: @revo Thank you, but the expression you gave isn't working with grep.  Do you know if there is anything in the syntax that would be different for grep than the live demo?

Comment: Some exception might not contain Exception in their name though. If that's the case, `grep -v '^[ A-Z]{2}'` (there's a space in that char class) might be worth a shot. (it assumes logs are always 1-line long and that naming conventions are respected and therefore the only lines that do not start with 2 spaces or caps are exceptions and their stacktraces)

Comment: Using GNU `grep` you could do `grep -P '(?m)^(?:\S+?Exception|\h+at )' file`

Comment: @revo That works, thanks again.  Feel free to answer and I'll up-vote you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Java +8 you could do:

```
(?m)^.*?Exception.*(?:\R+^\s*at .*)+
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/DFmNVD/1)

In grep however, since it processes one line at a time by default, you could match lines with `Exception` or those starting with `at`:

```
grep -P '(?m)^(?:\S+?Exception|\h+at )' file
```

Comment: This doesn’t include the `Caused by` sections of a stack trace.  And [Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) are throwables too, so `(Exception|Error)` is probably preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a complicated, non-portable regexp when you can do this trivially using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]/{f=0} /Exception/{f=1} f' file
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory$1.<init>(ClientIOFactory.java:17)
    at com.myCompany.client.ClientIOFactory.lambda$clientIOFactoryFromSocket$0(ClientIOFactory.java:15)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:83)
    at com.myCompany.client.queryData(Client.java:91)
    at com.myCompany.queryOptData(InstantAutomaton.java:153)
    at com.myCompany.AutoMain.main(InstantAutomaton.java:426)
```